# Tic Tac Toe , not swapping out numbers for X or O when prompted to

Tags: python, string, list, format

This is my code thus far: I need help realizing what the issue is in swapping out the numbers that appear as the "board" with an X or O. It prints out the board, asks for an X input, then prints out the board, updated with the X (or so I thunk) and prints it out again. It just prints out the same board with no X..

```
def initial_board(board_dimension):
    '''Returns an initialized board for the given board_dimensionension.'''
    board = []
    position = 1
    for i in range(board_dimension):
        sublist = []
        for j in range(board_dimension):
            sublist.append(str(position))
            position += 1
        board.append(sublist)
    return board

def print_board(board):
    
    for row in board:
        for i in row:
            print(i.rjust(5),end='  ')
        print()

def player_x_input(board):
    
    position_x = input("X position: ")

    for int in board:
        if int == position_x:
            int = 'X'    
    return board

def main():
    
    '''Your main function.  Do NOT change the given code.'''

    board_dimension = int(input("Input board_dimensionension of the board: "))
    board = initial_board(board_dimension)
    print_board(board)
    player_x_input(board)
    print_board(board)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def player_x_input(board):
position_x = input("X position: ")

for pos in range(len(board)):
    for elem in range(len(board[pos])):
        if board[pos][elem] == position_x:
            board[pos][elem] = 'X'
return board
```

This should do the work

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you assign to `int` (do not use this as a variable name as it is the name of a type) but that does not affect the list.

Consider iterating over the *indices* of your list instead of it's elements in this case.

```
>>> lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> for i in range(len(lst)):
...     if i == 5:
...         lst[i] = 1
...
>>> lst
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```